# Return JSON data from PHP, and use it using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, web-services, json, callback

I have worked with JSON data, Jquery's getJSON method to use PHP's server side scripts to get data. Now I am trying to work with JSON data being returned by a PHP function and a Javascript event or url would get that data. For a Javascript function to access PHP data, it has to have a callback, and I am not able to figure out, how I should create a callback.

Existing code that I have in the PHP file (getData.php) can echo/return JSON output and would give data that would look like this

```
{"count":3,"items":[{"myTab_ID":"1","myTab_xam":"test1","myTab_rank":"21"},
{"myTab_ID":"2","myTab_xam":"test2","myTab_rank":"22"},
{"myTab_ID":"3","myTab_xam":"test3","myTab_rank":"22"}]}
```

Now I have my javascript file which would be making the call, which would be a little twitter like,

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver/getdata.php">
      </script>
   </head>
 </html>
```

Now when I run this html file, I get an error saying

> "Error: invalid label Source File:
>   http://myserver/getData.php Line: 1,
>   Column: 1 Source Code:
>   {"count":3,"items":[{"myTab_ID":"1","myTab_xam":"test1","myTab_rank":"21"},{"myTab_ID":"2","myTab_xam":"test2","myTab_rank":"22"},{"myTab_ID":"3","myTab_xam":"test3","myTab_rank":"22"}]}"

in the error console.

I am a little happy that I atleast am able to get the data from my php side to the html file, but now I am wonder how would I use that returned JSON data. How would I develop the callback function that returns the JSON data back??

```
> ------code in getData.php---------------
> 
> $con =
> mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
> if (!$con)   {   die('Could not
> connect: ' . mysql_error());   }
> 
> mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
> 
> $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM
> Persons");
> 
> while($row =
> mysql_fetch_array($result))   {  
> $data[] = $row;   }
> 
> echo json_encode($data);
> 
> --------------end - getdata.php--------------
> 
> ---------code in getJson.html------------- html> <head>
> <script type="text/javascript"
> src="http://myserver/getdata.php">
> </script> </head>
> 
> </html>
> -----------------------end- getJson.html----------
```

I am not sure how a callback would work to get the data?

Comment: When putting code in your questions, just indent each line by 4 spaces.

Comment: @Pointy - you can also just highlight it and click the {} button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because that JSON construction is simply erroneous to the JavaScript parser.  After a naked open curly brace (`{`), Javascript expects a statement.

What your code seems to expect is that the JSON *not* be included simply as a `<script>` into a page, but instead that it be fetched actively by an XMLHttpRequest (i.e., "ajax").  That's really common, and it's quite different from what a `<script>` tag gives you. In such situations, the JSON construction is explicitly parsed by client-side code and used for, well, whatever is desired.

Comment: Correct; as-is, your HTML page is trying to include JSON as JavaScript, which fails. You need to assign it to a variable, either through an AJAX call, or the PHP page needs to output it as a variable (`var myData = {...}`).

Comment: how can I assign the output as a variable? do I just return the json_encode($data)?? or would I have write some javascript inside my php and return that??

Comment: If the PHP code wrote the JSON out  with a little Javascript around it, that would work fine, as others have noted. Just have the PHP code prefix that JSON with the JavaScript code to declare a variable, like `var x = { json stuff here };`

Comment: Assume $data contains the json data, so do I do a echo '<script> var myData = "<?php $data; ?>"</script>'; Is this what you would suggest Pointy?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget your header in getData.php:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

[Some useful examples in the php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: When I add this header, the file is coming up for download. As soon as I load a page, I am getting a prompt for downloading the getData.php file. Is this wierd?

Comment: Is that when you are trying to view the output through a browser? There are various methods of getting browsers to interpret application/json - eg. http://adallow.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/viewing-applicationjson-mime-type-docs-in-your-browser/

Answer (score 0):

if you want the json encoded $data array to be avaliable in javascript you can do this:

```
<?php $jencodeddata = json_encode($data); ?>
```

in your HTML file..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSOmething()
{    
var jsencodedata = '<?php print $jencodeddata ?>';
you can loop through jsencodedata here....
}
</script>
```

hope this helps.